# How to properly format this RestClient post with Authorization Header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
RestClient.post "https://example.com`", {"id"=>"","name"=>params[:company_name],"frate"=>"0.005"}.to_json,{:Authorization => bearertoken},{content_type: :json, accept: :json}
```

I receive the following error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 2..3)):
```

Answer (score 1):

You have passed the Authorization header correctly, but the other two headers you separeted when they should be together. Try like this:

```
RestClient.post "https://example.com`", {"id"=>"","name"=>params[:company_name],"frate"=>"0.005"}.to_json,{:Authorization => bearertoken ,content_type: :json, accept: :json}
```